# Python Regex match if string has X amount of words that start with @#$:

Tags: python, regex

What I'm trying to do is match strings if that string contains X amount (let's say 5) of words that start with @#$: characters.

Examples assuming X is 5:

```
@someword someotherword anotherword word1 word2 word3 => false
@someword :someotherword #anotherword $word1 word2 word3 => false
@someword :someotherword #anotherword $word1 #word2 $word3 => true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A positive lookahead would be one way to do this:

```
input = "@someword :someotherword #anotherword $word1 #word2 $word3"
result = re.match(r'.*((?<=\s)|(?<=^))[@#$:]\S+.*(\s[@#$:]\S+.*){4}', input)

if result:
    print("Found a match")
```

This question is tricky, because you want to match words with start a special symbol `[@#$:]`.  But, we can't just use word boundaries `\b`, because the special characters are not word characters.  So instead, we can check that what comes before the start of the target term are either whitespace, *or* the very start of the string.

Comment: I tested it as well and it works as I want it to be, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex assuming these symbols are only used before word characters:

```
(?:]\B[@#$:]\w+[^@#$:]*){5}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/clCwZV/1)

**Code:**

```
>>> arr = ['@someword someotherword anotherword word1 word2 word3', 
'@someword :someotherword #anotherword $word1 word2 word3',
'@someword :someotherword #anotherword $word1 #word2 $word3']
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?:\B[@#$:]\w+[^@#$:\n]*){5}');
>>> for i in arr:
...     print(reg.findall(i))
...
[]
[]
['@someword :someotherword #anotherword $word1 #word2 ']
```

- `\B`: Match where `\b` doesn't.
- `[@#$:]\w+`: Match 1+ word characters starting with `[@#$:]`
- `[^@#$:]*`: Match 0 or more characters not containing `[@#$:]`
- `(...){5}`: Match 5 of this in current input

Comment: I got your back bro, +1 to your answer :-)

Comment: Thanks Tim. Actually I had `\B` to start with but regex101 debugger was running into catastrophic backtracking so I removed it for demo purpose and copy/pasted incorrect regex here as well. In python it works pretty well though.

Comment: Yeah...I also abandoned Regex 101 very early, because I too was having issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import re

my_re = '[#@$:][a-zA-Z]*'
my_string = "#hello :my #name $is $stef"

print(len(re.findall(my_re,my_string)) >= 5)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks.
Code-wise, yes. But I need it as a regex as I use multiple regex and need to insert direct regex. Not sure if it's possible though.

Comment: Well I dont think you can get a True or False with only regex. You are not allowed to use re.match for example?

Comment: @vanderZonStef Yes, you can, using a really ugly regex pattern :P

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen check my answer below, it's simple pattern and definitely not ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Proper regular expression is `((?:[@#$].+){5})`. [Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/v0EZGb/1)

Example:

```
import re
...
tst = """
    @someword someotherword anotherword word1 word2 word3
    @someword :someotherword #anotherword $word4 #word5 $word6
    @someword :someotherword #anotherword $word1 word2 word3
    @someword :someotherword #anotherword $word1 #word2 $word3
"""
res = re.findall(r"((?:[@#$].+){5})", tst)
print(res)
```

Result:

```
['@someword :someotherword #anotherword $word4 #word5 $word6', '@someword :someotherword #anotherword $word1 #word2 $word3']
```

Comment: The problem with that, if you use more than one of those marks in a word, it will still match. https://regex101.com/r/Iztljn/1

Comment: Also, I don't think you are handling word boundaries here at all.  Wouldn't `a@someword` also match using your logic?

Comment: @Latyos in question you have not mentioned that provided symbols shouldn't be anywhere else except start. Anyway, with 3 small edits will fix it ;)